# Continuity at an inner point of an interval implies the continuity of the inverse

Tags: calculus, continuity, inverse

If a function $f$ with domain interval is $1-1$ and  continuous at an **inner**  point a of the interval its inverse is continuous at $f(a)$?

Comment: What definition of continuity do you work with?

Comment: A function f is continuous at c ∈ D if and only if, for all $\epsilon> 0$, there exists a
$\delta > 0 $ such that for all $x ∈ D, |x − c| < \delta$  implies $|f(x) − f(c)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: You may want to rewrite that using f-inverse and see why this should work if it is true for f.